# How to convert a base64 string to a png file with R?

Tags: r, base64, png

I have a png image encoded in a base64 string `mybase64`. How can I convert this base64 string to a png file ?

I've tried:

```
  conn <- file("xxx.png", open = "wb")
  base64enc::base64decode(what = mybase64, output = conn)
  close(conn)
```

But that does not produce a png file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution.

My base64 string:

```
mybase64 <- "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU......"
```

Then:

```
  raw <- base64enc::base64decode(what = substr(mybase64, 23, nchar(mybase64)))
  png::writePNG(png::readPNG(raw), "mypng.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :)

```
library(base64enc)

inconn <- file("xxx.bin","rb")
outconn <- file("xxx.png","wb")
base64decode(what=inconn, output=outconn)
close(inconn)
close(outconn)
```

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent base64 It should be written to xxx.bin in this sample

Comment: Ok, but I have a character string. How should I write it to `xxx.bin` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Have a look at [write to file in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/write.html).
A base64 string directly in code would be a bit nasty...